# How to avoid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException when doing migration

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, migration, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have one database and I need to do migration, in other words I need to move the data to another database. I have used EF, and generated automatically the classes with EDO. The problem occures at newDb.SaveChanges()
Here is my code:

```
        var oldDb = new oldBAEntity();
        var newDb = new NewDbContextEntities();

        var query2 = oldDb.R_ClaimHistory.ToList();

        foreach (var sourceObj in query2)
        {
            ClaimComment targetobj = new ClaimComment();

            targetobj.ClaimId = (int)sourceObj.IdClaim;
            targetobj.Comment = sourceObj.HistClaimDescription;
            targetobj.UserCreated = (int)sourceObj.IdUserCreated;
            targetobj.DateCreated = sourceObj.DateCreated;

            newDb.ClaimComments.Add(targetobj);
        }
        newdb.SaveChanges();
```

When I run it, I am getting this error :

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

InnerException :

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_ClaimComments_Claims\". The conflict occurred in database \"Toni-Bank-DB\", table \"dbo.Claims\", column 'ID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to insert a new ClaimComment when the Claims.ID does not exist (or does not match).

You will need to re-order your code to ensure all FKs exist before attempting to add a record which has the constraint defined.

Comment: yes, Chris. I stopped and thought for a half an hour. I found out that I am filling this table, and Claims table is empty, so I guess when I fill first Claims table and then fill ClaimsComments table, the error will not show again

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting to ClaimComment table you need to have corresponding ClaimId in Claim table. So First make sure Master table data are inserted and then go for child tables.